# How to integrate the AIS_INTERACTIVE_CONTEXT inside the GLArea?

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk, gtkmm, opencascade

I want to integrate the AIS_INTERACTIVE_CONTEXT inside the GLArea in order to display a model. The GLArea widget is taken from a Glade file. The code is incomplete becouse I dont know what to do next. The code is built with the help of https://github.com/gkv311/occt-samples-gtk , but there the author creates a completely new window, but I w ant to place the context inside the separate widget which is alreary inside the Gtk::Window

```
static gboolean render(GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context)
{
  glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  return TRUE;
}

static void realize(GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context)
{
  gtk_gl_area_make_current(GTK_GL_AREA(area));
}

GdkGLContext *create_context(GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context)
{
  GdkGLContext *new_context;
  Handle(OpenGl_Context) aGlCtx = new OpenGl_Context();

  new_context = Handle(GdkGLContext *) myContext; // myContext is of type 
  AIS_INTERACTIVE_CONTEXT

  std::cout << "kjdnkcl" << std::endl;

  return new_context;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

OSD::SetSignal(false);
OSD::SetSignalStackTraceLength(10);

OSD_Environment aBackend("GDK_BACKEND");
aBackend.SetValue("x11");
aBackend.Build();

Handle(Aspect_DisplayConnection) aDisp = new Aspect_DisplayConnection();
Handle(OpenGl_GraphicDriver) aDriver = new OpenGl_GraphicDriver(aDisp, false);
// lets Gtk::GLArea to manage buffer swap
aDriver->ChangeOptions().buffersNoSwap = true;
// don't write into alpha channel
aDriver->ChangeOptions().buffersOpaqueAlpha = true;
// offscreen FBOs should be always used
aDriver->ChangeOptions().useSystemBuffer = false;

// create viewer
myViewer = new V3d_Viewer(aDriver);
myViewer->SetDefaultBackgroundColor(Quantity_NOC_BLACK);
myViewer->SetDefaultLights();
myViewer->SetLightOn();
myViewer->ActivateGrid(Aspect_GT_Rectangular, Aspect_GDM_Lines);

// create AIS context
myContext = new AIS_InteractiveContext(myViewer);

myViewCube = new AIS_ViewCube();
myViewCube->SetFixedAnimationLoop(false);
myViewCube->SetAutoStartAnimation(true);

// note - window will be created later within onGlAreaRealized() callback!
myView = myViewer->CreateView();
myView->SetImmediateUpdate(false);
myView->ChangeRenderingParams().ToShowStats = true;
myView->ChangeRenderingParams().CollectedStats = 
(Graphic3d_RenderingParams::PerfCounters) 
(Graphic3d_RenderingParams::PerfCounters_FrameRate | 
Graphic3d_RenderingParams::PerfCounters_Triangles);

myContext->Display(myViewCube, 0, 0, false);

{
 // dummy shape for testing
 TopoDS_Shape aBox = BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(100.0, 50.0, 90.0).Shape();
 Handle(AIS_Shape) aShape = new AIS_Shape(aBox);
 myContext->Display(aShape, AIS_Shaded, 0, false);
}

GError *err = NULL;
ui_builder = gtk_builder_new();

gtk_builder_add_from_file(ui_builder, "./GLAreaWindow.glade", NULL);

window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(ui_builder, "Window"));
gl_area = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(ui_builder, "GLArea"));

g_signal_connect(gl_area, "render", G_CALLBACK(render), NULL);
g_signal_connect(gl_area, "realize", G_CALLBACK(realize), NULL);
g_signal_connect(gl_area, "create-context", G_CALLBACK(create_context), NULL);

gtk_builder_connect_signals(ui_builder, window);

gtk_widget_show_all(window);

gtk_main();

return 0;
}
```